# Создание нескольких кубов Directx12

Tags: c++, directx

Вот что я понимаю на данный момент:

1. **Создаю устройство**: получение доступа к видеокарте(этот этап понятен)
2. **Создаю swap chain**: создаю поверхность для отрисовки, создаю задние буферы которые будут меняться(это понятно)
3. **Командная очередь, список команд, fence и т.д.**: как я понял это типо создаётся объект, который описывает цепочку действий, которые будет выполнять видеокарта(здесь не сильно въехал)
4. **Конвеер стэйт обджект(PSO)**(это понял):

   4.4. **Root signature**: список параметров и собственно сами величины этих параметров, которые будут переданы в функцию шейдеров

   4.5. **Компилирование созданных шейдеров**: ну вроде понятно. Получаю потом объект двух шейдеров(вершинного и пиксельного) и потом буду вызывать их в каждой итерации.

   4.6. **Входная разметка**: описывает видеокарте структуру вершины

   4.7. **Задать PSO** используя соответствующий метод `device`(длинный чтобы писать)(уславливается в список команд вроде)
5. **Список вершин и индексов**: создаю массив структур вершин и индексов(в соответствии с тем как было описано в PSO) и распологаю их..., и тут немного запутался: мне нужно поместить их в память видюхи - default heap, но только видюха имеет доступ к этой памяти. Поэтому нужно создать default heap(хотя как это происходит, если нет к ней доступа?) потом создаю upload heap, помещаю ресурсы(вершины и индексы) туда, и добавляю команду в список команд на копирование с upload heap в default heap. В так вроде.
6. **Создаю глубинный/stencil буффер вьюпорт**: типо не сильно «важно», но вроде понятно(короче просто скопировал с примера и работает)
7. **Создание объктов**. Вот здесь у меня проблема. Вот код(это после объявления вершин, глубинного буфера и вьюпорта):

``

```
for (int i = 0;i<frameBufferCount;  i++) 
   { 

  hr = device->CreateCommittedResource(             &CD3DX12_HEAP_PROPERTIES(D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_UPLOAD),      
  // this heap will be used to upload the constant buffer data 
        D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_NONE,           // no flags 

          &CD3DX12_RESOURCE_DESC::Buffer(1024 * 64), // size of the resource heap. Must be a multiple of 64KB for single-textures and constant buffers 


           D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_GENERIC_READ, // will be data that is read from so we keep it in the generic read state 
        nullptr, // we do not have use an optimized clear value for constant buffers 

     IID_PPV_ARGS(&constantBufferUploadHeaps[i])); 

          constantBufferUploadHeaps[i]->SetName(L"Constant Buffer Upload Resource Heap"); 

    ZeroMemory(&cbPerObject, sizeof(cbPerObject)); 

    CD3DX12_RANGE readRange(0, 0);    // We do not intend to read from this resource on the CPU. (so end is less than or equal to begin)                                    // map the resource heap to get a gpu virtual address to the beginning of the heap 


    hr = constantBufferUploadHeaps[i]->Map(0, &readRange, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&cbvGPUAddress[i])); 

    // Because of the constant read alignment requirements, constant buffer views must be 256 bit aligned. Our buffers are smaller than 256 bits, 

    // so we need to add spacing between the two buffers, so that the second buffer starts at 256 bits from the beginning of the resource heap. 

    for (int ii = 0; ii < 1000;ii++) 
    memcpy(cbvGPUAddress[i] + ConstantBufferPerObjectAlignedSize*ii, &cbPerObject, sizeof(cbPerObject)); 
} 

// Now we execute the command list to upload the initial assets (triangle data) 
commandList->Close(); 
ID3D12CommandList* ppCommandLists[] = { commandList }; 
commandQueue->ExecuteCommandLists(_countof(ppCommandLists), ppCommandLists);
```

Короче, когда делаю `ii` меньше, например, 100 всё работает потом норм, рисуются 100 кубов. Но если поставить 1000, программа кидает исключение на вызове `memcpy:

```
0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу 0x1B31A008
```

В `Update()` у меня такой же цикл, и в `UpdatePipeline()` у меня тоже цикл с вызовами `DrawIndexedInstanced`, но до этого не доходит - исключение на этапе инициализации, получается.

---

Пожалуйста, поправьте если я что-то понимаю не так, и объясните почему возникает исключение?

---

[Учу здесь](https://www.braynzarsoft.net/viewtutorial/q16390-transformations-and-world-view-projection-space-matrices)

---

**Обновление**

Окей, я поменял размер кучи, как указал Alex F, и всё заработало, но теперь при, всего лишь, 3000 кубах лагает очень сильно, где-то пару фпс, и картинка как-бы заедает: отрисовывается а потом отображает предыдущее состояние а потом снова отрисовывает дальше.
В `Update()` у меня только изменение матрицы вращения для каждого куба

Comment: @AlexF, сейчас попробую

Comment: @AlexF, сработало) Странно, потому что я уже пробовал это менять. Правда теперь странно отрисовывается и достаточно медленно, но Вы, как я понимаю не по DirectX) Спасибо